# How to make a button containing only an image accessible?

Tags: html, image, accessibility

I have an `<img>` that is when clicked should **perform an action**, so I wrapped it inside a `<button>` like this:

```html
<button>
    <img src="" alt="Cat">
</button>
```

Regarding accessibility, a button in the accessibility tree should have a **role** and **label** associated to it. The role is done using `<button>` tag and normally, a button's label is its content inside the opening and closing tags, but in our case there's only an image.

So how to make the button accessible in this case? Is the `alt` attribute enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Regarding accessibility, a button should have role and label.

You should only provide a `role` if the default semantics of the element don't give it one. A `<button>` is a submit button. It doesn't need a `role` if you are using it for that.

Likewise, a `label` should only be provided if there isn't an intrinsic one. The content of a `<button>` labels it, and your `<img>` element has an `alt` attribute.

> So how to make the button accessible in this case? is the 'alt' attribute enough?

Yes.